# Regex that matches between two strings, including the first string

Tags: regex

Let's say I have a string:

`var n = 10`

I'd like a regex which matches the following portion:

`var n`

I've tried:

`var(.*?)=`

But that only matches:

`n`

Comment: In this case try `(var.*?)=`

Comment: What language or tool are you using ?

Comment: try this. (var\\s[a-z]=)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not wrap the whole thing with parentheses like this:

```
(var.*?)=
```

Comment: @JacksonGariety Are you surprised or you are making fun of my answer ?